# Parent less not applying to child while using & operator

Tags: css, less

```css
    .text1 {
        font-weight: normal;
        font-family: cursive;
        color: green !important;
    
        &-xxs {
            font-size: smaller;
        }
    
        &-sm {
            font-size: small;
        }
    
        &-md {
            font-size: medium;
        }
    
        &-lg {
            font-size: large;
        }
    }
```

```html
<div class="text1-sm">
```

doesn't have `text1` properties .
I want the properties of text1 to be applied in addition to that of `sm` when using `text1-sm` as the class name

Answer (score 0):

CSS doesn't work that way.

`text1` and `text1-xss` are different class names.

The selector `.text1` simply doesn't match an element with `class="text1-xss"`.

---

You could give the element both classes: `class="text1 text1-xss"`

---

You could design the CSS to just use two different classes in the first place:

```css
.text1 {
  font-weight: normal;
  font-family: cursive;
  color: green !important;
}

.xss {
  font-size: smaller;
}
```

with `class="text1 xss"`.

---

You could use a [mixin](https://lesscss.org/features/#mixins-feature) to copy the shared rules into each class selector ruleset.